# What's the correct way to store and get the enum of a child-class?

Tags: java, performance, enums, storage

Let us presume we're dealing with a "classic" code-example:

I have the classes `Animal`, `Cat`, `Dog`, `Horse` and some more animals.
`Animal` is an abstract class which all the animals extend.

Additionally, I also have the enum `AnimalType`:

```
public enum AnimalType {
    CAT, DOG, HORSE, ...
}
```

This is a scenario where using such an enum is neccessary. I am aware of instance testing and casting, and prefer using it to identification by enum. But it is needed here, so please refrain from turning this into a debate about that if possible.

**Question**:

Which of the following is the correct way to go and/or more efficient performance wise?:

a)

```
public abstract class Animal {

    @Getter private final AnimalType type;

    public Animal(AnimalType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

or

b)

```
public abstract class Animal {

    public Animal() {
    }

    public abstract AnimalType getType();

}

public class Cat extends Animal {

    @Override
    public AnimalType getType() {
        return AnimalType.CAT;
    }

}
```

In words: Should i store the enum of a child class in a member of the parent abstract class or make it "quasi-static" return from an abstract method?

Comment: "I am aware of instance testing and casting, and prefer using it to identification by enum" ideally you'd use neither: you'd just use straight polymorphism, and never need to care about the type of the subclass.

Comment: "Which of the following is the correct way to go and/or more efficient performance wise?" they are equally correct, and I doubt there is any meaningful performance difference. I would go for a) because it's less boilerplate than explicitly overriding the getter in all the subclasses.

Comment: @AndyTurner – What about of having a `List<Animal>` and now wanting all the cats from it? Straight polymorphism does not do the job here, you need a discriminator now – either the `enum` as suggested here, or the concrete subclass …

Answer (score 2):

My preference is for approach a): storing the `enum` in the base class and providing a final `getter` for it.
The second approach does not force the contract that `getType()` will always return the real animal type, because an implementation could look like this:

```
public class DraftAnimal extends Animal
{ 
  …

  @Override
  public final AnimalType getType() 
  {
    // DO NOT DO THIS!
    return today.equals( christmas ) ? AnimalType.REINDEER : AnimalType.HORSE;
  }
}
```

Confessed, the sample looks silly … but you want to block those silly ideas right from the design.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you shouldn't care about performance in this case, because both memory footprint of your objects and cost of calling getters are likely to be the same (very cheap).

As soon as you are using abstract class with some common functionality I'd suggest approach b) for consistency with the rest of the code (in case we have only those two options you suggest).

Alternatively, you could have `protected final` field in your abstract class along with the getter. Something like this:

```java
public abstract class Animal {
  @Getter protected final AnimalType type;

  public Animal(AnimalType type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
  public Cat() {
    super(AnimalType.CAT);
  }
}
```

This approach encapsulates all the common code in your abstract class, but requires the type to be explicitly passed in constructors of inherited classes.

Comment: Why is AnimalType access protected? Subclasses should not need to access this field in particular.

Comment: Why not? `protected` allows subclasses to avoid calling getter to access the field

Comment: Is there a signifcant difference between a child class using a getter and calling a protected field from it's parent abstract class? If so, what is it?

Comment: Why having a getter for a field with `protected` access? if the field is used only inside the class hierarchy, the `protected` access is sufficient. And when it is used outside, there has to be a getter, so that this can be used also from inside the hierarchy, and the field itself can be `private`.

Comment: @SergeyTsypanov I don't think just because it allows subclasses not to call the getter is valid reason to give `protected` access. If the subclass needs direct access, then sure thing, but there should be a specific reason.
@jaylawl The difference should be negligible.